# Asp.net C# - Update a listbox at runtime

Tags: runtime

I'm developing an asp.net c# website, is there a way to update a ListBox, or an equivalent control, in real time so that it shows the list of files contained in a given folder?
This is because, for each file identified, it is necessary to perform a series of checks at the end of which I would like to inform the user of the result, without waiting for the check of all the files, which can be many.

This is my attempt:
aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="listBoxFiles" runat="server" Width="300" Height="600"></asp:ListBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function updateListBox() {
                
                var updatePanel = document.getElementById('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>');
                
                __doPostBack(updatePanel.id, '');
            }
        </script>
    </form>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/REPOSITORY/"));
            foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles("*.xml"))
            {
                testFile(file.Name);
            }
        }


        private void testFile(string file)
        {
            listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
            //simulate load
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "updateListBox", "updateListBox();", true);
        }
```

What I get is displaying all the block of files located in the folder and not one by one.

Thanks in advance